# Why can't I call Nim proc without braces?

Tags: nim-lang

Nim support proc calling expression without braces, but when I use named arguments it complains, why?

```
proc doc(text: string) {.discardable.} = echo text
doc "doc1"
doc(text = "doc1")
doc text = "doc1" # <== Error here
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The complain is `Error: undeclared identifier: 'text'`, because you're calling the `doc` proc with a value that is undeclared. This works:

```
proc doc(text: string) = echo text

let text = "doc1"
doc text
```

The line `doc text = "doc1"` tells the program to 1) call the procedure `doc` with the variable `text` as first argument and 2) assign "doc1" to whatever that procedure returned. And so you'll find the error `Error: 'doc text' cannot be assigned to`.

Comment: Thanks, although I find this behaviour non-intuitive and confusing.

Comment: Then use braces. Nim has this philosophy of enabling multiple coding styles (functional, procedural, OOP), but doesn't force any of them. Pick up what you enjoy the most and keep coding :) .

Answer (score 1):

```
proc doc(text: string = "") = echo text
doc text = "hello world"
```